# Copy data to postgres+postgis from csv file with special formated polyline

Tags: database, postgresql, csv, gis, postgis

I am working with Postgres+Postgis to handle spatial data, i was using a dataset with CSV files (id,timestamp,latitude,longitude) and i was copying the data from the CSV files into the database like so:

```
cat mycsv.csv | psql -d mydatabase -c "COPY mytable (id ,datetime ,lat ,lon) from stdin WITH DELIMITER ','"
```

Now i am using a diferent dataset of CSV files and im having trouble copying it to the database.
The new CSV file has a polyline and is formated like this:

```
val1,val2,val3,"[[-8.618643, 41.141412], [-8.618499, 41.141376], [-8.620326, 41.14251]]"
```

I wanted to import the polyline into a geometry array or as a text field (WKT), my final goal is to import the polyline and store it as a geometry type line in a table.

The problem is, since the delimiter is ',' and the polyline is an array of coordinates separated my ',' i get the obvious error:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
```

Is there a way of having more than 1 delimiter, or a diferent aprouch for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you already can import the csv to postgres and your table will have a string field `geom_text`

The problem is the format of you string. `geom_text`

If you look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text the format of `MULTILINESTRING`

```
 MULTILINESTRING ((10 10, 20 20, 10 40),
                  (40 40, 30 30, 40 20, 30 10))
```

So you have to use string replace to chage `[]` for `()`
Then append the keyword `MULTILINESTRING`

And then use the function **[ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html)** to create your object geom.

```
 SELECT ST_GeomFromText(updated_geom_text) FROM YourCsvTable;
```

Comment: i understant. The problem is i cant import the csv into postgres due to the delimiter beeing ','.
Will I really have to change the format of the CSV file, its pretty big. Is there someway  of not capturing the commas inside the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat mycsv.csv | psql -d mydatabase -c "COPY mytable (id ,datetime ,lat ,lon) from stdin WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV"
```

You need to specify the CSV mode, you are currently just telling it to use the delimiter.

Comment: This does nothing for working to get the malformed *linestring* into a PostGIS geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem using sed, awk and regex to modify the dataset.

Then used ST_GeomFromText function to get the line from text.